# Accessing data in a javascript object that has the same name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a javascript object that looks similar to this:

```
var data = {
  Message: {
       sent: 'complete',
       received: true,
       time: '4:06 PM' 
   },
  Message: {
       sent: 'complete',
       received: false,
       time: '9:01 AM' 
   },
  Message {
     ...... // and so on
   }    
}
```

And I want to access each one of the `sent`, `received` and `time` objects and push them to an array.So for example, it might look like this when its done:

```
['complete', 'complete', 'Not complete'] // sent
[true, true, false]  // received 
['4:06 PM','9:01 AM', '2:00 PM' ] // time
```

I know this is pretty basic, but I'm not sure how to get every one of `sent`, `received` and `time`, only the last one (relatively new to js).

How can I get every one of `sent`, `received` and `time`? I'm pretty sure I could figure out the array portion, however if you include it in the solution I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Object keys must be unique. That is likely invalid JS. Use an array instead.

Comment: Are you sure it's not `[{Message: ....}, {Message: ....}]`,, notice the `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have two keys in an object with the same name. Instead try an array:

```js
var messages = [
  {
    sent: 'complete',
    received: true,
    time: '4:06 PM' 
  },
  {
    sent: 'complete',
    received: false,
    time: '9:01 AM' 
  },
  {
    sent: 'complete',
    received: false,
    time: '1:01 PM' 
  }    
];

messages.forEach(
 (message) => {
   console.log(message.sent, message.time);
 }
);
```